# Solana Metaplex Creator Split issue

Tags: typescript, solana, metaplex

I'm using the Metaplex Storefront for testing purposes. I've added 2 whitelisted wallets for my auction page via the admin page(one of the whitelisted wallet is that I used to initialize the page).
I've made a test auction with this nft(https://explorer.solana.com/address/E7Hmkff1kPiYMJdFbLxRe9vp5Ba9cEuwntwxFusddCb5?cluster=devnet) that have 2 creators with 50-50 split and the NFT is verified, but when the auction ended only the auction starter wallet received the full amount of the money. Here is the tx:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/E7Hmkff1kPiYMJdFbLxRe9vp5Ba9cEuwntwxFusddCb5?cluster=devnet

Auction:
https://jester91.github.io/metaplex#/auction/3S8sAb1vMxjF9F54WYEbpX8hnvhCzgNbk5j7Z3d87KJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creators array works for secondary sales (marketplaces for example), splitting the royalties percentage obtained on secondary sales over the creator array addresses.

For example, your NFT has a 4% on the seller fee, and ur creator array share is set to 50-50, then each creator will receive 2% of any secondary sale money from that NFT.

`That Metadata Account holds a lot of valuable information that can be used throughout the ecosystem. For instance, it maintains a list of creators for the token. Each creator has a Verified attribute that, when True, guarantees the token was signed by that creator. Each creator also has a Share attribute that can be used by marketplaces to distribute royalties.` [(from the official metaplex docs)](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview)